# Não deixar inserir mesmo valor em um DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Possuo um `DataGridView` onde eu tenho uma coluna chamada `Ramal`, onde irá o ramal do vendedor específico.

Como fazer para que quando eu digitar em uma linha um ramal já existente, aparecer uma mensagem que não pode ser inserido? Conforme exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os eventos ideais para tal validação são o ColumnChanged e o RowChanged.
ColumnChanged ocorre logo depois que o usuário alterou o valor de uma coluna
sendo o ideal para uma validação coluna a coluna. O RowChanged ocorre depois
que o usuário concluiu a alteração na linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vá no evento do seu `DataGridView` e escolha a opção `CellEndEdit`.

Dentro desse método de evento insira o seguinte código:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string v = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value?.ToString().Trim();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Index >= this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) break;
        if (row.Cells[3].Value?.ToString().Trim() == v && row.Index != e.RowIndex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Opa, já existe um ramal igual a esse");
            this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = null;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`Cells[3]` é a coluna onde está localizada os ramais.

Quando alguém digitar um ramal que já existe na coluna, vai aparecer a mensagem.